# How to read and delete a file in an external storage from another app in Android?

Tags: android, io

I am working on a little project with 2 apps. I have made a text-file in the 1. app and saved it here: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`. After that i worked with the 2. app which i have to save the data from my file (made in the 1. app) to an Sqlite database online.
My problem is how can i get to the file, read it or delete it and further?
Any help is very appreciate. Thanks,- Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, I think this is complete solution:

```
String text = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+ "/ParentFolder/Child");
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    text = bfr.toString();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: My problem is i don't know how to read/reach the file (made in 1.app) from my second app? if is it possible?

Comment: I did that (from my 2.app): File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        File file = new File(path, fileName); and if (file.isFile()) i get the file dosen't exist! But the file exist and is stored in the 1.app!

Comment: Use that code in both apps and inspect what value is of `path.getAbsolutePath()`. Are they the same?

Comment: Actually you should compare `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: You mean: compare file.getAbsolutePath() for 1. app and 2.app?

Comment: Ali Motameni, the path is my problem? i tried that: File file = new File(path + "H:/AndroidStudioProjects/CMN/Test/Test4/app", fileName); and path: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); - /app is my 1.app. But it dosen't work!

Comment: What do you mean by this: "/ParentFolder/Child" ?

Comment: This is what i try to found out: i save the file in: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); in my 1.app (H:/AndroidStudioProjects/CMN/Test/Test4/app), but i don't know how the path is down to my file?

Comment: `compare file.getAbsolutePath() for 1. app and 2.app? `. Yes. Log that and compare the logs. Or/And Toast() them and compare them. Are they the same? Please post the paths here.

Comment: `H:/AndroidStudioProjects/CMN/Test/Test4/app), but i don't know how the path is down to my file? –`. Your comment makes no sense to me. H: is a Windows partition. What does it have to do with a path on an Android device?

Comment: File path1/2 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); from app1: /storage/sdcards/Documents and from app2: /storage/sdcards/Documents. This is the same path?!!

Comment: Well simple isn't it? Just put your files there and all apps can find them. You could also make your own directory in it.